# spring setting up 2 disparcher sevlets and security

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to make a CMS in Spring and I have problems setting up 2 dispatcher servlets. (Also I am new to spring)

And I want to have this structure:

`app/...` (my site with all my pages)

`app/cms/...` (my cms part of the site where I can manage my content)

So, I defined 2 dispatcher servlets:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>app</display-name>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>cms</display-name>
    <servlet-name>cms</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cms</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cms/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

also with 2 xml files `cms-servlet.xml` and `app-servlet.xml` both with the correct package location and jsp resolver with correct location for jsp files

now I'm trying to set up security and a login form. My `security-context.xml`:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/cms/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/cms/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/cms/login" />
</security:http>
```

Problem is I get an error:

```
Mai 18, 2014 10:35:32 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/cms/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'cms'
```

My custom login.jsp (of course with the correct tags for spring to process it) is under the cms jsp files. And the controller for login is in package that I defined in `cms-servlet.xml`. If I change these 2:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
<security:form-login login-page="/login" />
```

I get an error on my browser complaining about `This webpage has a redirect loop`.

What is the problem ? Is how I set the 2 dispatcher servlets correct ?

PS: my Login Controller from cms package:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String showLogin() {
    return "login";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the warning:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/cms/login] 
in DispatcherServlet with name 'cms'
```

does your controller map `/cms`? Something like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cms")
public class CmsController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String showLogin() {
        return "login";
    }
```

Comment: yes, here was the problem .. I had `@Component` and not `@Controller` because I used autocomplete when I wrote `@Co` and I didn't pay attention but I paid with one full day for this.